# How do we activate (on demand) an object that is a property of another object?

Tags: delphi, oop, file-io

I am implementing an object TTextFile that is a framework for using the low level pascal file function with the OO paradigm. I want to add to developers the option to use it as a TStringList when needed in the same object, like this:

```
 TTextFile = class(TObject)
   constructor Create(FileName: String);
   procedure OpenForRead;
   procedure OpenForWrite;
   {...}
   property Content: TStringList;
 end;
```

But my problem is that I want the `Content` property to use user `LoadFromFile` only at the first time the application uses it. Not in the `Create` construction, because the file might be too big, and the programmer would prefer to use the other functions in this case. The `Content` would be use when he knows the file he is using will not be very big.

An example of a big file is a list with all the client names and citizen ID. An example of a very tiny file is that same list, but only with the clients that are waiting to be attended in the current day.

Is it possible to be done in OO pascal? If it is not possible, I will have to make a kind of activation procedure or an overload `Create` and make the programmer always check if the `Content` is loaded before use it.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using the modern `TStream` classes (which give you the "OO paradigm", buffer I/O, have built in exception support, and support Unicode)?

Comment: Does `TStream` support finding a string in a certain line of the file and then return that line and not the entire file? My concert is to load a huge file into memory without need.

Comment: There are certainly `TTextStream` classes around that do it, with source. My point is that you should be doing it based on descending from one of the `TStream` classes like `TFileStream` instead of wrapping the old "low level pascal file functions".

Comment: Why the downvote? Should I know all about OO and Delphi? It's kind paradoxical...

Comment: Just for the record, the downvote was not from me.

Comment: If it where, you wouldn't bother to write an answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the concept of *lazy initialization*. The first time the `Content` property is read, load the file contents, but then *keep* the contents available so that subsequent accesses of the property don't re-read the file.

```
private
  FContent: TStrings;
  function GetContent: TStrings;
public
  property Content: TStrings read GetContent;

function TTextFile.GetContent: TStrings;
begin
  if not Assigned(FContent) then begin
    FContent := TStringList.Create;
    try
      FContent.LoadFromFile(FFileName);
    except
      FContent.Free;
      FContent := nil;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
  Result := FContent;
end;
```

Comment: Can we do that with TStringList instead of tStrings? It we can, that's the perfect solution!

Comment: @EASI: A TStringlist is a TString's descendant, so whatever you can do with TStrings, you can do with TStringList.

Comment: +1. You obviously did a better job of reading the requirements than I did. :-)

Comment: I would then take it a step further by implementing a custom `TStrings`-derived class that internally uses a memory mapping to access the file data, that way there is no need to keep the whole file in memory at one time.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly this is possible.

Change your class declaration:

```
TTextFile = class(TObject)
   constructor Create(FileName: String);
   procedure OpenForRead;
   procedure OpenForWrite;
   function GetContent: TStringList;
   {...}
   property Content: TStringList read GetContent;
 end;
```

and implement it:

```
function TTextFile.GetContent: TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  Result.LoadFromFile(FFileName);  // Presumes FileName is stored in FFileName in constructor
end;
```

Comment: I thought of that too, and them I thought the possibility of not needing to create a `TStringList` out of the object. But that answer will be my option if what I want can't be done.

Comment: What if I call `Content` twice?

Comment: We should Call `Content[0]` to get 'James' for example. But then should be an internal test to check if Content is loaded if the file already.